# Cannot open pdf file in USD drive by Adobe Reader using Window Vista

Tags: usb-flash-drive

A message popped up as below

> Adobe Reader could not open file because it is either not a supported
>   file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was
>   sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)

Comment: Either the USB key has a problem, either the file has a problem. Look at permissions. Is something, somewhere, locked? Try moving the file to your computer before opening it. If it's still not working, the file has been damaged, somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. I understand that a message has popped up, but you haven't said what you want to do/know about it. Do you want to open it, or understand how it got into this state? Were you expecting a different type of warning?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ariane's comment. Although password protected pdf's ask straight for a password. My guess is the file has either:

1. Saved incorrectly from the owner / 1st user
2. Uploaded incorrectly onto the flashdisk
3. It got corrupted somewhere a long the way

I will try to go to the source of the file and try again.